# iterate a LinkedHashmap<String,ArrayList<Object>> in JSP

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets

how to iterate a `LinkedHashmap<String,ArrayList<Object>>` in JSP to obtain the elements in the value part i.e. the ArrayList ????

below is the code :-

```
package com.test2.mainClass;

import java.io.*;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.*;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;



public class Servlet1 extends HttpServlet {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.doGet(req, resp);
        System.out.println("In doGet()");

    }



    @Override
    protected void service(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.service(req, res);

        Servlet1 s1 = new Servlet1();
        s1.method();
        int i = 1;
        if(i==1){


        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = 
                req.getRequestDispatcher("/exceloutput.jsp");
            dispatcher.forward( req, res );
            return;
        }

    }

    int rowIndex;
    int columnIndex;


    //***********************************************************************************
    //Taking the Standard Headers in variables
    private static String key1 = "Product";
    private static String key2 = "Model";
    private static String key3 ="Part Number";
    private static String key4 ="U_PRE";
    private static String key5 ="P_PRE";
    private static String key6 ="U_ENHP";
    private static String key7 ="P_ENHP";
    private static String key8 ="U_ENH";
    private static String key9 ="P_ENH";
    private static String key10 ="U_BASIC";
    private static String key11 ="P_BASIC";
    //***********************************************************************************                                                               


    //Creating One Master MAP which will be iterated to obtain values
    public static Map<String,ArrayList<Object>> M = new LinkedHashMap<String,ArrayList<Object>>();


    //!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
    //Lists for every particular key
    static ArrayList<Object> productList = new ArrayList<Object>();
    static ArrayList<Object> modelList = new ArrayList<Object>();
    static ArrayList<Object> partnoList = new ArrayList<Object>();
    static ArrayList<Object> u_preList = new ArrayList<Object>();
    static ArrayList<Object> p_preList = new ArrayList<Object>();
    static ArrayList<Object> u_enhpList = new ArrayList<Object>();
    static ArrayList<Object> p_enhpList = new ArrayList<Object>();
    static ArrayList<Object> u_enhList = new ArrayList<Object>();
    static ArrayList<Object> p_enhList = new ArrayList<Object>();
    static ArrayList<Object> u_basicList = new ArrayList<Object>();
    static ArrayList<Object> p_basicList = new ArrayList<Object>();
    //!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

    public void method(){
        try {


            FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\Users\\SoniAd\\Desktop\\TOOL WORK EXCEL\\Copy of Original Sheets\\New.xls"));

            //Get the workbook instance for XLS file 
            HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(file);

            //Get first sheet from the workbook
            HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

            //Iterate through each rows from first sheet
            Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
            Row row;
            //Check if there is next row present in the excel sheet
            if(rowIterator.hasNext()) 
            {
                rowIterator.next();//Go to next row
            }
            if(rowIterator.hasNext()) 
            {
                rowIterator.next();
            }
            while(rowIterator.hasNext()) {
                 row = rowIterator.next();

                //For each row, iterate through each columns
                Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
              //Check if there is next cell present in the row
                if(cellIterator.hasNext()) 
                {
                   cellIterator.next();//Go to next cell
                }

                while(cellIterator.hasNext()) {

                    Cell cell = cellIterator.next();

                    //Get the type of entry in the cell
                    switch(cell.getCellType()) {
                        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:

                            break;
                        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:

                            rowIndex = cell.getRowIndex();
                            columnIndex = cell.getColumnIndex();
                            if(rowIndex>2)
                            {
                                if(columnIndex==7)
                                {
                                    u_preList.add(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                                }
                                if(columnIndex==8)
                                {
                                    p_preList.add(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                                }
                                if(columnIndex==9)
                                {
                                    u_enhpList.add(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                                }
                                if(columnIndex==10)
                                {
                                    p_enhpList.add(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                                }
                                if(columnIndex==11)
                                {
                                    u_enhList.add(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                                }
                                if(columnIndex==12)
                                {
                                    p_enhList.add(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                                }
                                if(columnIndex==13)
                                {
                                    u_basicList.add(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                                }
                                if(columnIndex==14)
                                {
                                    p_basicList.add(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                                }
                            }
                            break;
                        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:



                       //Skip iterations for first three keys   
                      if(cell.getStringCellValue()!=key1||cell.getStringCellValue()!=key2||cell.getStringCellValue()!=key3||cell.getStringCellValue()!=key4||cell.getStringCellValue()!=key5||cell.getStringCellValue()!=key6||cell.getStringCellValue()!=key7||cell.getStringCellValue()!=key8||cell.getStringCellValue()!=key9||cell.getStringCellValue()!=key10||cell.getStringCellValue()!=key11)
                            {
                                rowIndex = cell.getRowIndex();
                                columnIndex = cell.getColumnIndex();


                                if(rowIndex>2 && cell.getStringCellValue()!=null)
                                {
                                    if(columnIndex==1)
                                    {
                                        productList.add(cell.getStringCellValue());
                                    }
                                    if(columnIndex==2)
                                    {
                                        modelList.add(cell.getStringCellValue());
                                    }
                                    if(columnIndex==3)
                                    {
                                        partnoList.add(cell.getStringCellValue());
                                    }

                                }

                            }
                            break;
                    }
                }


                System.out.println("");
            }
      //Entering data (keys and their respective values
                    M.put(key1,productList);
                    M.put(key2,modelList);
                    M.put(key3,partnoList);
                    M.put(key4,u_preList);                  
                    M.put(key5,p_preList);
                    M.put(key6,u_enhpList);
                    M.put(key7,p_enhpList);
                    M.put(key8,u_enhList);
                    M.put(key9,p_enhList);
                    M.put(key10,u_basicList);
                    M.put(key11,p_basicList);


            file.close();
            FileOutputStream out = 
                new FileOutputStream(new File("C:\\Users\\Ad\\Desktop\\TOOL WORK EXCEL\\Copy of Original Sheets\\New.xls"));
            workbook.write(out);
            out.close();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }




try {

    //$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$

             String serviceType = null;
             String serviceProgram = null;
             double price = 0;

    //$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$      

    //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

             String choiceValuePremium = null;
             String choiceValueEnhancedPlus = null;
             String choiceValueEnhanced = null;
             String choiceValueBasic = null;

    //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^        

             String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@sv-decdb1.ecom.fjcs.net:1522:ECOMDEV";
             //Create Connection object
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "dev",
                    "dev");
            // Create statement object
            Statement st = conn.createStatement();
            //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

            //FOR PRE

            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select choicevalue from TABLENAME where choicedescription = 'Premium'");
            while(rs.next()){
            choiceValuePremium = rs.getString("choicevalue");

            }

            //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

            //FOR ENH PL

            ResultSet rs1 = st.executeQuery("select choice_value from TABLENAME where choicedescription = 'Enhanced +'");
            while(rs1.next()){
            choiceValueEnhancedPlus = rs1.getString("choicevalue");

            }

            //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

            //FOR ENH

            ResultSet rs2 = st.executeQuery("select choicevalue from TABLENAME where choicedescription = 'Enhanced'");
            while(rs2.next()){
            choiceValueEnhanced = rs2.getString("choicevalue");

            }

            //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

            //FOR BAS

            ResultSet rs3 = st.executeQuery("select choicevalue from TABLENAME where choice_description = 'Basic' and rownum<1");
            while(rs3.next()){
            choiceValueBasic = rs3.getString("choicevalue");

            }
          //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            //Store entry (Key/Value)of HashMap in set
            Set mapSet = (Set) M.entrySet();
            //Create iterator on Set 
            Iterator mapIterator = mapSet.iterator();


            System.out.println("Display the INSERT Queries of every Entry in the Excel.\n");
            while (mapIterator.hasNext()) {
                    Map.Entry mapEntry = (Map.Entry) mapIterator.next();
                    // getKey Method of HashMap access a key of map
                    String keyValue = (String) mapEntry.getKey();
                    //getValue method returns corresponding key's value
                    //ArrayList<Object> value = (ArrayList<Object>) mapEntry.getValue();
                    ArrayList<Object> value = M.get(keyValue);
                    //KKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKK


                    System.out.println("\n\n\n");
                    System.out.println("------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
                    System.out.println("------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
                    System.out.println("------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
                   System.out.println(keyValue);


          //%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%         
                    FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\Users\\SoniAd\\Desktop\\TOOL WORK EXCEL\\Copy of Original Sheets\\New.xls"));

                    //Get the workbook instance for XLS file 
                    HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(file);

                    HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

                    //&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&

                    for (int k = 0; k<=sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows()-5;k++)
                    {  
                        //System.out.println(k);
                    if(keyValue==key4||keyValue==key5)
                    {
                        serviceProgram = choiceValuePremium;

                        if(keyValue==key4){
                            serviceType = "U";
                            price = (Double) u_preList.get(k);

                        }
                        if(keyValue==key5){
                            serviceType = "P";
                            price = (Double) p_preList.get(k);

                        }
                    }
                    if(keyValue==key6||keyValue==key7)
                    {
                        serviceProgram = choiceValueEnhancedPlus;

                        if(keyValue==key6){
                            serviceType = "U";
                            price = (Double) u_enhpList.get(k);

                        }

                        if(keyValue==key7){
                            serviceType = "P";
                            price = (Double) p_enhpList.get(k);

                        }

                    }
                    if(keyValue==key8||keyValue==key9)
                    {
                        serviceProgram = choiceValueEnhanced;

                        if(keyValue==key8){
                            serviceType = "U";
                            price = (Double) u_enhList.get(k);
                        }
                        if(keyValue==key9){
                            serviceType = "P";
                            price = (Double) p_preList.get(k);
                        }

                    }
                    if(keyValue==key10||keyValue==key11)
                    {
                        serviceProgram = "041";
                        if(keyValue==key10)
                        {
                            serviceType = "U";
                            price = (Double) u_basicList.get(k);

                        }
                    if(keyValue==key11)
                    {
                        serviceType = "P";
                        price = (Double) p_basicList.get(k);

                    }

                    }

                    if(keyValue!=key1&&keyValue!=key2&&keyValue!=key3){ 
                        //++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
                        System.out.println("**********************************");
                        /*System.out.println(k);
                        System.out.println(productList.get(k));
                        System.out.println(modelList.get(k));
                        System.out.println(serviceType);
                        System.out.println(serviceProgram);
                        System.out.println(price);
                        System.out.println(partnoList.get(k));
*/                      //+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
                         String insertQuery = "INSERT INTO TABLENAME ("productive,modeling,servicetype,serviceprogram,price,effectivedate,expirydate,createuser,createdate,pricetype,gsaprice,systemboards,manhours,partnumber,updatedate,updateuser,gsacode)"+"VALUES('"+productList.get(k)+"','"+modelList.get(k)+"','"+serviceType+"','"+serviceProgram+"',"+price+",SYSDATE-1,to_date('31-DEC-99','DD-MON-RR'),'system','SYSDATE','EXTENDED',null,null,null,'"+partnoList.get(k)+"',null,null,null)\n";
                        //st.executeUpdate(insertQuery);
                    System.out.println(insertQuery);
                    }

                    }//end of FOR Loop

             //%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%     

            }//end of WHILE loop

            conn.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Got an exception! ");
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

here is the jsp code:-

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>

     <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core_rt" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<table border = '1'>


<th>Product</th>
<th>Model</th>
<th>Service Type</th>
<th>Service Program</th>
<th>Price</th>
<th>Effective Date</th>
<th>Expiry Date</th>
<th>Create User</th>
<th>Create Date</th>
<th>Price Type</th>
<th>GSA Price</th>
<th>System Boards</th>
<th>Man Hours</th>
<th>Part Number</th>
<th>Update Date</th>
<th>Update User</th>
<th>GSA Code</th>





</table>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to display the values(which I am obtaining in the Insert query) on the browser in the form of a table. I have tried c:forEach loop to iterate the LinkedHashMap> (to obtain the entries in the ArrayList), but its not working . Any help is appreciated....

Below is the code of the servlet:-

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Map<String,ArrayList<Object>> M = Product.method();

        request.setAttribute("M", M); // Will be available as ${M} in JSP
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/output.jsp").forward(request, response);
        return;
    }
```

Comment: I am not able to write the correct code for iterating the LinkedhashMap<String,ArrayList<Object>> and obtaining the elements in the ArrayList<Object> (which is the value part of the LinkedHashMap). I want to add them in the html table ....

Comment: this all needs to be done in jsp page ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best way to iterate the map through entry set,

```
public static Map<String,ArrayList<Object>> M = new LinkedHashMap<String,ArrayList<Object>>();

for(Map.Entry<String,ArrayList<Object>> entry : M.entrySet()){
    for(Object obj:entry.getValue()){ 
       ....
    }
}
```

And in JSP

```
<c:forEach var="entry" items="${M}">  
      <option>${entry.key}</option>  
      <c:forEach var="val" items="${entry.value}">       
           ....
      </c:forEach>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The code in Java is fetching the whole ArrayList<Object> and is fine.... But the code in JSP(which I want to use) is not displaying any output. May be I am entering it wrongly. Can you show that code between the two forEach loops. I am new to this , so please help.... Thanks in advance ...

Comment: there is assumption in jsp code, that you have passed the map as M, what I meean is `request.setAttribute("M",M);`

Comment: Well if you dane that then please debug your jsp code `<c:forEach var="entry" items="${M}">  
      <option>${entry.key}</option>  
      <option>${entry.value}</option>  
</c:forEach>`

Comment: I am adding the code which I have use in servlet....Please check it if it is right ??..

Comment: ummm code is bit messy, But I could not find anywhare you have set the attribute of your `LinkedHashMap`. you should write `request.setAttribute("M",M);` at the end of your servlet

Comment: hey, that "you should write request.setAttribute("M",M); at the end of your servlet " helped..... Thanks...I got it on the browser but all the values are displayed at the same time, i.e. all the arraylists with their respective entries. I want the 'first' entries of all the arrayLists in a single row (which will be the first row of the html table)...